# ELISP: How to trap display-completion-list to a variable

Tags: elisp

I have a list of targets and I want to write a function where you can choose the
current target. My code looks like that below.

The problem is that when I do "M-x my-test", `current_target` is set as `nil` and the chosen
address is printed on the current buffer.

How do I trap the buffer output to `current_target`? Or my whole approach is wrong?

Please advice? Which doc to read?

Thanx

-Siddhartha

```
(defvar target-list '( ("10.25.110.113" " -> target-1") 
    ("10.25.110.114" " -> target-2")) "List of Target boxes")

(defvar current-target "0.0.0.0" "Current target")

(defun my-test ()
  (interactive)
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Target List*"
    (princ "\nPlease click on IP address to choose the target\n\n")
    (setq current-target (display-completion-list target-list))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what behavior you want. But if you just want to let a user choose one of your strings, then try using `completing-read`:

```
(defun my-test ()
  (interactive)
  (setq current-target  (completing-read "Target: " target-list nil t)))
```

Or if you want to return the associated target then look up the string chosen in your alist:

```
(defun my-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let (target)
    (setq current-target  (completing-read "Target: " target-list nil t)
          target          (cdr (assoc current-target target-list)))
    (message "Target: %s" target)))
```

You get the idea.

Comment: And if the function also has non-interactive utility, you could make `target` an argument to the function, and then handle the `completing-read` as part of the `(interactive)` form.

Comment: @phils: Yes, there are lots of possibilities. Dunno just what is intended/needed. That's why I added "You get the idea". The suggestion is to use `completing-read`. How that's used is up to the OP.

Comment: Thanx a ton for the idea of assoc. Actually I want to display the target names the user and when the user picks on the name then set the IP address to current-target.

Please read the code below and code-review it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
;; The code for the question after the reply from Drew is as follows
;; The idea is to present to the user names to choose from.
;; Thanx Drew for "giving the idea"

(defvar target-assoc-list '( ("Fire"  . "10.25.110.113")  ("Earth" . "10.25.110.114")
             ("Water" . "10.25.110.115")  ("Air"   . "10.25.110.116"))
 "The assoc list of (name . ip-addr) so that user chooses by name 
  and current-target is assigned the ip address")


(defvar current-target "0.0.0.0")

(defun my-select-target ()
   (interactive)
   (let (name)
       (setq name (completing-read "Enter Target (TAB for list): " 
                                    target-assoc-list nil t)
             current-target (cdr (assoc name  target-assoc-list)))
       (message "Chosen current-target IP address: %s name: %s" current-target name)))
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. If you don't need to save `current-target` you can just use a `let*` binding (for both `name` and `current-target`.